# Why aren't variable names surrounded by exclamation marks outputting values even after enabling delayed expansion?

Tags: batch-file

I wrote this code:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "var1=level"
set "var2=stats"
echo !var1%var2%!
```

and when I execute it, it outputs this:

```
!var1stats!
```

Even with Delayed Expansion enabled, exclamation marks won't work in substitution of parenthesis.
I want it to output this:

```
levelstats
```

I don't understand my error.

Comment: Because you get `!var1stats!`, you must have executed the test on the command line. But you can't enable delayed expansion on the command line with `setlocal` only by starting the console by `cmd.exe /V:on`

Answer (score 2):

You never tell the `%var1%` variable to expand, so it doesn't.

---

Let's trace this out:

> `echo !var1%var2%!`
>   1. `%var2%`gets expanded first to be `stats`, so now you are left with `!var1stats!`
>   2. `!var1stats!` is not a defined variable, so it simply gets displayed

If you're looking to expand both `%var1%` and `%var2%`, just do that with `echo %var1%%var2%`. You don't even need exclamation points unless you have a variable called `%levelstats%` that you're trying to print the value of, in which case `echo !%var1%%var2%!` will print the value of `%levelstats%`.